# How to set the paper page layout to two columns like this?

Tags: two-column

[image: I want to typeset my paper(exercise book ) like this.]

I am a latex typesetting beginer.I want to typeset a booklet which has A4 paper size as the picture I show here.My target page layout looks like the picture.

1.In order to save space I will set the paper to 2 columns.

2.On the top center of the two columns is some characters describing the property of the    questions.

3.I would like to set the paper to be two sides as the picture shows on the odd paper number on the top right and those on the next even page.Can this be completed by filling the text within the headline or headnote environment?

4.I will set the right and left sides width to 1.5cm,the top about 2.1cm,the bottom 2.0cm.

5.Customizing the  multi choices questions' choices is really a tricky thing for me , would you please give me some advice?Such as which document class may satisfy my requirement better?

I also wonder if there are some good template meet my require.

This is my basic code:

```
 \documentclass{exam}
 \usepackage{xeCJK}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
      %\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=.2in,left=.5in,right=.5in,top=.5in,bottom=.3in,footskip=.    25in]{geometry}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
   \fbox{\fbox{\parbox{5.5in}{\centering
    谢谢各位朋友 \qquad 谢谢各位朋友}}}
\end{center}

\vspace{0.1in}

  \makebox[\textwidth]{Name and s好人:\enspace \hrulefill}

  \vspace{0.2in}

  \makebox[\textwidth]{Instructor's name:\enspace \hrulefill}

  \begin{questions}
  \question

    (本题满分14分 衡水十月模拟)\\已知函数$f(x)=a^x+x^2-x\ln a \, (a >0,a \neq 1)$.\\
    (1)求函数$f(x)$在点$(0,f(x))$处的切线方程；\\
    (2)求函数$f(x)$的单调递增区间；\\
    (3)若存在$x_1,x_2 \in [-1,1]$,使得$|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\ge e-1$\,($e$是自然对数的底数),求  实    数$a$的取值范围.

      \end{questions}


     \end{document}
```

Would you please give me some help? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you tried providing the document class option `twocolumn`, i.e., writing the document's very first instruction as `\documentclass[twocolumn]{exam}`?

Comment: @Mico thank you ,now I add the option,it works well. Would you please give me some advice about adjusting the margin(top,bottom,left,right)of the paper layout?Thanks.

Comment: Please ask specific questions separately, one by one, and check before if a question was already answered.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use the `multicol` package and use the `multicols` environment to indicate the part(s) of the document that should be typeset in two-column format. Unlike the document class option `twocolumn`, the `multicol` package will balance the contents of the columns. *Addendum*, prompted by a comment by @DG': If you do *not* want to balance the contents of the columns, you could use the environment `multicols*` (instead of `multicols`).

To set the page margins, use the `geometry` package.

There have been many questions on this site regarding the placement of page numbers; I suggest you peruse some of them to find a solution that meets your needs.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{exam}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{amsmath,multicol}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=1.5cm,top=2.1cm,bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\fbox{\fbox{\parbox{5.5in}{\centering
谢谢各位朋友 \qquad 谢谢各位朋友}}}

\vspace{0.3in}

\makebox[\textwidth]{Name and s好人:\enspace \hrulefill}

\vspace{0.2in}

\makebox[\textwidth]{Instructor's name:\enspace \hrulefill}
\end{center}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{questions}
\question

(本题满分14分 衡水十月模拟)\\已知函数$f(x)=a^x+x^2-x\ln a \, (a >0,a \neq 1)$.\\
    (1)求函数$f(x)$在点$(0,f(x))$处的切线方程；\\
    (2)求函数$f(x)$的单调递增区间；\\
    (3)若存在$x_1,x_2 \in [-1,1]$,使得$|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\ge e-1$\,($e$是自然对数的底数),求  实    数$a$的取值范围.

\question

(本题满分14分 衡水十月模拟)\\已知函数$f(x)=a^x+x^2-x\ln a \, (a >0,a \neq 1)$.\\
    (1)求函数$f(x)$在点$(0,f(x))$处的切线方程；\\
    (2)求函数$f(x)$的单调递增区间；\\
    (3)若存在$x_1,x_2 \in [-1,1]$,使得$|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\ge e-1$\,($e$是自然对数的底数),求  实    数$a$的取值范围.

\end{questions}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution.By my understanding the multicols enviroment fill the paper space in horizon,I would like to fill the left side of one paper then the other side.Would you please help me again?

Comment: Have you tried the non balancing environment `multicols*`?

Comment: @DG' - Thanks. I've incorporated your comment/suggestion into my answer.