# Making a horizontal & vertical continuous list

Tags: lists

I'm looking to make assignments and tests in latex article class. I want to be able to do the following very easily:

[image]

Couple things: I would like the text in a) or c) to wrap around the imaginary "break" between the two columns. Also, it would be nice if the procedure kept track of the counters together for both columns; otherwise, this might as well be done in MS Word - I'm porting over to LaTeX for the math mode.

Comment: Perhaps a good start: [How to set the paper page layout to two columns like this?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142932/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tasks` for the inner list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[more]{tasks}

\NewTasks[style=enumerate,counter-format=tsk[a]),label-width=2.6ex,column-sep=2ex,before-skip=2pt,item-indent = {1em}]
                        {questions}[\subquestion](2)
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[nosep]
  \item Answer any  of the following questions as you wish.
  \begin{questions}
    \subquestion How are you doing? If doing well, answer this question.
    \subquestion How are you doing? If doing well, answer this question.
    \subquestion How are you doing? If doing well, answer this question. How are you doing? If doing well, answer this question.
    \subquestion How are you doing? If doing well, answer this question.
  \end{questions}
  \item You don't have to answer any of these questions as they may be difficult.%  << this % is needed
  \begin{questions}
    \subquestion How are you doing? If doing well, answer this question.
    \subquestion How are you doing? If doing well, answer this question.
    \subquestion How are you doing? If doing well, answer this question. How are you doing? If doing well, answer this question.
    \subquestion How are you doing? If doing well, answer this question.
  \end{questions}
  \item You don't have to answer any of these questions as they may be difficult.%  << this % is needed
  \begin{questions}
    \subquestion How are you doing? If doing well, answer this question.
    \subquestion How are you doing? If doing well, answer this question.
    \subquestion How are you doing? If doing well, answer this question. How are you doing? If doing well, answer this question.
    \subquestion How are you doing? If doing well, answer this question.
  \end{questions}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks that's an awesome solution; however I can't seem to compile it or really find out why this isn't working. I get a couple of errors:

LaTeX error: "kernel/key-unknown" The key 'tasks/list/column-sep' is unknown and is being ignored.

Any thoughts? Really would like to get this to work thank!

Comment: @DanP. You need an up to date tex distribution. Please update and it will work.

Comment: Awesome! Everything works perfectly now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

A solution with the `shortlst` and `enumitem` packages. You can choose the number of columns (key `nc`, 3 by default), the interlining to take into account big formulae (key `il`, 1 by default) and the distance between item label and item body (key `ls`, 0.6em by default).   If necessary, an item will *automatically* use more than one column.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{shortlst, setspace, amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\newlist{exercises}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[exercises,1]{label=\arabic*. , wide=0pt}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{tabenumerate}{\renewcommand\theenumi{\alph{enumi})}
\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\mbox{(m)}}}


\makeatletter
\newcounter{ncol}
\define@key{lex}{nc}[3]{\setcounter{ncol}{#1}}%% 3 columns by default
\define@key{lex}{il}[1.5]{\def\@intln{#1}}% interlining![1]
\define@key{lex}{ls}[0.6em]{\setlength{\labelsep}{#1}}%%distance between label and item body
\newenvironment{tabenumerate}[1][]{%\setlength\labelsep{0.6em}
\setkeys{lex}{nc,il,ls, #1}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep\relax}%[1][3]
\setlength{\shortitemwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth/\value{ncol}-\labelwidth-2\labelsep\relax}%
\setstretch{\@intln}
\begin{shortenumerate}\everymath{\displaystyle}}%
{\end{shortenumerate}
 }%
 \newcommand\paritem[2][1]{\item \parbox[t]{#1\shortitemwidth}{\setstretch{1}#2\medskip}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{exercises}
\item For the following questions, \&c. \vspace{-\baselineskip}
 \begin{tabenumerate}[nc=3, il =2.5, ls =1em]
 \item $ a_n = \frac{4n^3 - (-1)^nn^2}{5n + 2n^3}$
 \item $ b_n = \frac{(n^3 - 5n)^4 - n^{12}}{n^{11}}$
 \item $ c_n = \frac{n^{n + 1}}{n!}$\label{q-3}
 \item $ e_n = \frac{2^{(n^3)}}{n!5^{(n^2)} - n^n}$
 \item $ f_n = \sqrt{n + \sqrt{2n}} - \sqrt{n + \sqrt{2n}}\mkern1mu x$
 \end{tabenumerate}
\end{exercises}
See question \ref{q-3}.

\end{document}
```

[image]